# Android studio change async task to a handler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, handler

I need to change this application so that it uses a `Handler` rather than an `AsyncTask` to run the fake download. I've been stuck on it for a while. I have tried using samples to figure it out but I think the Notification thread confuses me. Doing my head in.

```
public class Responsive extends AppCompatActivity {

// 5. Declare and populate a string array for the ListView items (put this directly underneath the class declaration)
private static final String[] LIST_ITEMS = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_responsive);

    // 4. Call setupButton() and setupListView() from the onCreate method.
    setupButton();
    setupListView();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_responsive, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// 3. Open Responsive.java for editing and add the following three methods to it (don’t get rid of any of the existing code):

private void setupListView() {
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, LIST_ITEMS));
}

private void setupButton() {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createNotification();
        }
    });
}

private void createNotification() {
    new Downloader(getApplicationContext()).execute(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class NotificationHelper {

    private Context mContext;
    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mNotification;
    public NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private PendingIntent mContentIntent;
    private CharSequence mContentTitle;
    public NotificationHelper(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Put the notification into the status bar
     */
    public void createNotification() {
//get the notification manager
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mContentTitle = mContext.getString(R.string.content_title);
//create the notification
        mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_download)
                .setContentTitle(mContentTitle)
                .setTicker(mContext.getString(R.string.download_ticker))
                .setOngoing(true);

//Text of the notification in the notification drawer
        CharSequence contentText = "0% complete";
        mNotification.setContentText(contentText);
//we are not going to use the pending intent,so just create a blank one
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        mNotification.setContentIntent(mContentIntent);
//show the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification.build());
    }

    /**
     * Receives progress updates from the background task and updates *the notification bar
     * @param percentageComplete
     */
    public void progressUpdate(int percentageComplete) {
        //build up the new status message
        CharSequence contentText = percentageComplete + "% complete";
        //publish it to the notification
        mNotification.setContentText(contentText);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification.build());
    }

    /**
     * called when the background task is complete, this removes the *notification.
     */
    public void completed(){
        //remove the notification from the status bar
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }

}
```